# In Zephyr for JIRA testdetails history I do not see the addition of test steps. Only updates and deletions. How can I find the additions

Tags: jira-zephyr

In Zephyr for JIRA testdetails history section  I do not see the addition of test steps.  Only updates and deletions.  How can I find the additions?

Answer (score 0):

Zephyr for JIRA testdetails history will provide only the information related to modification/deletion of the test steps as the create event is not captured.
We would track this as a feature request so that our product management team will review to consider for future versions.